# Magento 2: how to delete orders containing specified product_id?

Tags: magento2, orders, delete

I have an annoying bug in the Bestsellers table on the Dashboard page showing incorrect info about the non-existing products with weird prices and quantity sold.

I found that this row is collected of the products with product_id=0.

So, I need to delete all orders containing product_id=0 and all related data - invoices, shipments, credit memos, anything else related to these orders that may cause issues if not cleaned.

How can this be done in PHP or MySQL, please? I'm running Magento 2.4.3.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the order collection using this one :

```
protected $_order;
protected $orderRepository;

 public function __construct(\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $order, \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository $orderRepository)
 {
    $this->_order  = $order;
    $this->orderRepository  = $orderRepository;
 }

 public function execute()
 {
    $orderCollection = $this->_order->create();
    
    $product_id = 0; //YOUR PRODUCT ID

    $orderCollection->getSelect()
            ->join(
                'sales_order_item',
                'main_table.entity_id = sales_order_item.order_id'
            )->where('product_id = '.$product_id);

        $orderCollection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');

        foreach ($orderCollection as $order) {
             $this->orderRepository->delete($order);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not skilled enough to write necessary code for order and related data deletion. I don't even understand where and how to insert your code :-(

Comment: The code need to write like on any controller action which perform the task of delete the order for you.

Comment: I just added the delete code as well, now you just need to impertinent into your controller or something.

Comment: Is it possible just to create and run separate php file with necessary code?
Also, does the delete($order) function deletes specific order only, or all data related to it (like invoices, shipments, credit memos)?
Thank you.

Comment: yes you can create seprate like root script or something. Delete only orders. And if above answer help then upvote and accept as solution so it will help other in community.

Comment: The problems is that you think I'm a programmer or developer. I'm just an user who knows echo command in php :-) I believe your advice is good, but I can't use it with my poor skills. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I've found how to create a root script and wrap your code into a class. But it gives me following error during attempt to create new instance of the class.
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Abcd123::__construct(), 0 passed in /srv/public_html/pub/od.php on line 92 and exactly 2 expected in /srv/public_html/pub/od.php:60 Stack trace: #0 /srv/public_html/pub/od.php(92): Abcd123->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in /srv/public_html/pub/od.php on line 60

Comment: In root script there is not constructor way. you need to implement this things into separate way.

Comment: I did this finally without classes using just collection models. Your solution maybe correct, but my low skills did not allow me to implement it. Thank you anyway - you pointed me to right direction.

Comment: If my answer help you then upvote and accept as solution, so it will help others in community.